# Zend framework 2 error: unable to render template

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm working on [this tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/index.html). I have followed all steps to create directory structure, controllers, module.php and module.config.php, but when I open `http://zf2-tutorial/album` I get the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "album/album/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file' in /var/www/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php:461
```

I have created a file named `index.phtml` inside module directory in view/album/album directory.

`module.config.php`:

```
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',       
        ),
        'view_manager' => array(
            'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'album/album/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/album/album/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
                ),
            'template_path_stack' => array(
                'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            )
        )
    ),

    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I had this problem simply due to a fat-finger typo.  My `module.config.php` had this `'tempalte_path_stack' => array(`. `template` was misspelled, and caused this error.

Comment: Please check your module.config.php for the view-manager rendering is correct or not. also check your Controller and action passed has the same name. if you changed the action name then please check the file name (.phtml) also.

Answer (score 6):

The PhpRenderer object is complaining because it cannot find the view phtml file.

Does the file `module/Album/view/album/album/index.phtml` exist? If not then that's likely the cause.

Comment: I'm assuming you have created the Album module as specified in the tutorial? Some of that configuration suggests that's the Application module (therefore `__DIR__` would be incorrect).

Answer (score 4):

check if you have provided the correct parameters or nesting for your **view_manager** in the **module.config.php** file

Comment: if I'm using a Json view strategy, and getting the OP's message.. where is a doc to decipher what exactly to do here?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. I've changed the below line of file module.config.php,
Existing in the document,

```
'view_manager' => array(
  'template_path_stack' => array(
  'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
  ),
),
```

to

```
'view_manager' => array(
  'template_path_stack' => array(
  'album' => __DIR__ . '/../src/view',
  ),
),
```

Just add src folder name in front of view folder.

Like this, you need to add 'src' folder name before all the view paths.

Answer (score 1):

You should return a `view` object in `IndexController` like

```
$view = new ViewModel(array('albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),));
$view->setTemplate("album/album/index/index.phtml");
return $view;
```

instead of directly returning

```
return array('albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your codes with Album module. Everything is fine. You may have a problem with htaccess file. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Your view_manager is in wrong place. It should be on "controllers" and "router" level, not inside "controllers". Look at module.config.php in Application module and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you use forward slash and not backslash when in the **template_map** array which is inside the **view_manager** of the **module.config.php**

Answer (score 0):

Apart from this you need to add 2 things in module.config.php
in routes array put below code

```
'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
        ),
```

and translator array along with language folder

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't 'home' route anymore in Album\config\module.config.php
so

it's necessary to replace 'H/home' to 'A/album' in ..\module\Album\view\layout\layout.phtml

Comment: And add of course:   'translator' => array(
      'locale' => 'pl_PL',
      'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
          'type'     => 'gettext',
          'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
          'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
      ),
    ),

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the trouble was in the view file name. I named it `index.php` instead of `index.phtml`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, i didn't create empty view files
    module/Album/view/album/album/index.phtml
    module/Album/view/album/album/add.phtml
    module/Album/view/album/album/edit.phtml
    module/Album/view/album/album/delete.phtml

Answer (score 0):

check your application.config.php module name if it is 'Album' not 'album'
change

```
'template_path_stack' => array(
    'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view', => //to 'Album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
),
```